# Can Apple Watch Series 2 control Homekit devices with Siri?

Tags: siri, apple-watch, watchos, homekit

Can the New Apple Watch 2 control Homekit enabled devices like the Philips Hue with Siri voice commands like the iPhone can?

I'm thinking of buying an Apple Watch and I need to know whether or not I can control my Hue bulbs with Siri right from the Watch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, even W original can!
Check this video https://youtu.be/pyQuP5MKsUs @4.05

[image]